# My page is scrolling when there's nothing to scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress, layout

I have a little experience with dabbling in css but I cannot figure this out. I bet there is only one number somewhere thats wrong but I cant find it.

I was wondering if someone could please help

Website: www.maxanthonyphotography.com/portfolio

P.s The website isn't finished yet anyway but my ocd is driving me mad

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the style.css file you have around line 2120

```
div {
    height: 650px;
    (etc)
}
```

This will mean that all div tags on the page will have a height of 650px (unless you override it with a class or something).

for now try changing that line to `height: 100%;`

for future reference (depending on the browser) right click on the page and go to inspect element, this will show you what is going on with different elements on the page.

Comment: Hi thanks, i will try the 100%, but i have already tried the inspect element (on chrome) but i still couldn't narrow it down

Comment: It's alright. After a while you'll just get use to seeing things that are out of place. It's definitely a good idea to have a play around with things to find out what works and what doesn't, however, I would suggest using something like Twitter bootstrap and just making small changes as you need to. If you do use Bootstrap don't change the code in the bootstrap file, just create a new filegive the element you want to change another class name and add the css to the new file...if it doesn't work you can use `!important`. It's only a suggestion but it I think it might be a better way to go.

Comment: It will still scroll a bit because you have padding and margin on you elements as well